# Pulling all Customers modified in QuickBooks since certain datetime using .NET Dev Kit

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

IDS proper accepts querying by StartCreatedTMS/EndCreatedTMS to retrieve objects modified in QuickBooks only - not data services.

The IPP .NET Dev Kit seems to only expose the CDCAsOf property though.  Am I missing something and/or is there a way to query by StartCreatedTMS for QB Desktop via the .NET Dev Kit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.CustomerQuery customerQuery = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.CustomerQuery();
customerQuery.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType4[] { ItemsChoiceType4.StartCreatedTMS, ItemsChoiceType4.EndCreatedTMS };
customerQuery.Items = new object[] { new DateTime(2012, 01, 01), new DateTime(2013, 01, 01) };
List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer> customersList = customerQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbd.Customer>(context).ToList();
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for but after further investigation it's clear StartCreatedTMS is specific to transactions and I'm attempting to pull lists.

My greater issue is that - in attempting to develop a customer sync tool - when I programmatically update a customer in QuickBooks (cloud), once the sync manager pushes it from the cloud to QuickBooks it updates the timestamp.  And so when I run a subsequent sync, that same record is coming back the other direction even though no real changes have been made.

Comment: Please post your code. I tried with the API explorer and didn't have any issues.